# CASE THEN clause always evaluated

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm doing a `SELECT` which uses `CASE` to convert nvarchar values into a proper type, something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @propType = 'money' THEN convert(money, datavalue)
    [...]
    ELSE datavalue
END
FROM [...]
```

However, it seems the `convert` is always executed, even when `@propType` is *not* equal to money. Runnable example:

```
declare @proptype nvarchar(50)= 'nvarchar'
declare @val nvarchar(10) = 'test'
select 
    case @proptype
        when 'money' then convert(money, @val)
        else @val
    end
```

Why is this, and how can I get around it? The MSDN documentation says this:

> The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops
>   with the first condition whose condition is satisfied. In some
>   situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE statement
>   receives the results of the expression as its input. Errors in
>   evaluating these expressions are possible. Aggregate expressions that
>   appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE statement are evaluated first, then
>   provided to the CASE statement. For example, the following query
>   produces a divide by zero error when producing the value of the MAX
>   aggregate. This occurs prior to evaluating the CASE expression.

I'm not sure this is relevant, but the language is somewhat heavy for a non-native, so maybe it is?

Comment: The only purpose of explicitly converting a `varchar` to `money` when it's implicitely converted back to `varchar` is, afaik for formatting purposes so why don't you either store it in the required formatting to begin with or let the client handle the formatting?

Comment: The source data is not under my control. In the actual case I have to jump through quite a few hoops to get the data into such a format that I can insert it into the report table for which it is destined (which is properly typed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following [Use caution when Using CONVERT() with CASE or IF functions in Transact SQL (T-SQL)](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/sql/sqltip10.asp)

> The first thoughts are generally one of the following "Since the first
>   value evaluated is numeric, it is converted to decimal, and all other
>   data is expected to be a decimal as well" OR "If SQL Server is able to
>   convert ANY of the values to the specified type, then all values are
>   expected to be of the converted type".  However, that's not correct
>   (although the second is close)!
>
> The real problem is that if you choose to Convert the values anywhere
>   within the Case statement, the datatype you are converting the values
>   to is the expected type of ALL the values regardless of if they are of
>   that type or not.  Further, even if NONE of the values can actually be
>   converted (even if the Convert line of code never executes), ALL of
>   the values are still expected to be of the type specified by the
>   Convert function!

Comment: Thanks, this illuminates the why, but there is really no way forward from it?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear about what is happening the `then` clause is **not** being evaluated.

You see the same error if you do

```
SELECT CASE @proptype
         WHEN 'money' THEN $1.0 /*<-- Literal of datatype money*/
         ELSE @val
       END
```

The documentation for [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) explains that the Return Type

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   `result_expressions` and the optional `else_result_expression`. For more
>   information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

`money` has higher datatype precedence than `nvarchar` so the `else @val` is evaluated then that gets cast to `money` and fails.

One possible workaround would be to cast it to `sql_variant` as this has higher data precedence than both.

```
declare @proptype nvarchar(50)= 'nvarchar'
declare @val nvarchar(10) = 'test'
select 
    case @proptype
        when 'money' then convert(money, @val)
        else cast(@val as SQL_VARIANT)
    end
```