# When querying with (case when) Get an error message

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with a query:

When querying without (`case when`), the result appears correctly.

When querying with (`case when`), I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1142889.00' to data type int.

Code:

```
DECLARE @MessageIn nvarchar(100) = 'رصيدك الحالي هو 1142889.00 YER'

SELECT
    ISNUMERIC(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(@MessageIn, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @MessageIn), 50), PATINDEX('%[^0-9-.,]%', SUBSTRING(@MessageIn, PATINDEX('%[0-9-]%', @MessageIn), 50) + 'X') - 1), ',', ''), ',', '.') AS nvarchar(100)))

SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Left(SubString(@MessageIn, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @MessageIn), 50), PatIndex('%[^0-9-.,]%', SubString(@MessageIn, PatIndex('%[0-9-]%', @MessageIn), 50) + 'X') - 1), ',', ''), ',', '.') AS nvarchar(100))) = 0 
            THEN 0  
            ELSE ISNULL(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Left(SubString(@MessageIn, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @MessageIn), 50), PatIndex('%[^0-9-.,]%', SubString(@MessageIn, PatIndex('%[0-9-]%', @MessageIn), 50) + 'X') - 1), ',', ''), ',', '.') AS nvarchar(100)), 0) 
     END AS pl
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CASE THEN clause always evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898427/case-then-clause-always-evaluated)

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` also is not a good function. It returns false positives and false negatives. For example `ISNUMERIC(N'1142889.00'`) returns `1`, however `CONVERT(int,N'1142889.00')` will give the error you have. `ISNUMERIC` simply tells you that *at least* one of the numerical data types will successfull convert the value; it doesn't tell you which. Use `TRY_CONVERT`; it's vastly better.

Comment: @Larnu I was about to say: it doesn't even do that. `ISNUMERIC('.') = 1`. But then I found out `CONVERT(money, '.') = 0.0` for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: @Charlieface could be "worse"... `ISNUMERIC('2d6') = 1`. I know *why*, but have fun figuring that one out. :P

Comment: Thank you all. I think these comments are very very helpful and they are the correct answer

Comment: ISNUMERIC('2d6') = 1        this is a disaster

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, I get an conversion error. The issue was that `then 0` needed to be an nvarchar, not an integer: `then N'0'`